# VmWare: How do I mute the beep sound coming from the guest OS?

Tags: vmware-workstation

Even disabling the host beep service (`Computer > Manage > Device Manager > Non-Plug and Play Drivers > Beep > Stop`) does not stop the guest OS from beeping on the host when clicking around a messageBox to change focus for example.

Even adding headphones does not prevent the beep from happening.

How do I mute it ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add

```
mks.noBeep = "TRUE"
```

to your .vmx file to disable the PC speaker in this VM

Comment: See also [Turning off the PC speaker for all virtual machines](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1664)

Comment: Finally, I can wear headphones without my ears bleeding every time I hit tab in the Linux terminal!

Comment: Thank god, we are not working on walmart anymore

Answer (score -3):

In **System** -> **Preferences** -> **Sound** -> **System Beep** -> uncheck **Enable system beep**

Comment: Doesn't work in Workstation 11