# How do I disable the beep sound coming from the guest OS for VM Fusion?

Tags: vmware-fusion

I'm using VM Fusion 10.1 on macOS 10.13 and trying to disable the beep sound coming from the guest OS.

I tried the suggestion on https://superuser.com/a/379960/1100842 which I guess comes from the official [kb](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1664).

Add

```
mks.noBeep = "TRUE"
```

to my .vmx file

[image]

[image]

However, each time I restart my guest OS, the file is overwritten and my modification is gone.

I guess it's because the solution only applies to VM Workstation.

How do I disable the beep sound for VM Fusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mks.noBeep = "TRUE"` is the correct configuration option to add.  It should work across VMware products and is not specific to VMware Workstation.

- Make sure that you power off the VM and close Fusion *before* modifying the `.vmx` file.  Otherwise the `.vmx` file might be overwritten with the version loaded in memory.
- If I remember correctly, the `.encoding` line must come first since that defines how the rest of the file should be read.  Anything that precedes that line might get discarded.